# Python urllib retrieve is slow

Tags: python, request, urllib

So I am trying to parse a JSON file of Magic the Gathering image urls and download them.

I wrote the script below and was banging my head against the wall before each request was taking upwards of 3 or 4 minutes to download. I thought at first I was being throttled by the site, but that wasn't the case.

I ended up switch from my cmd shell to a git bash shell, ran the script, and it worked as intended so I believed I solved it. Well now even in a git bash shell the code is going slow and the only thing that was changed was the set I was looking in. I tried disabling the output throttle with '-u' but that doesn't help.

The "done" never gets printed, even though I know its loading all the json.

If I put a print statement in the for loop before my if check, "done" gets printed. It will get to the printing of the first filename but thats it.

```
import json
import urllib
import time

with open('scryfall-oracle-cards.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


print("done")
count = 0

for x in data:
    if x['set'] == "dom":
        cropUrl = x["image_uris"]["art_crop"]
        cardname = x['name'].replace(' ', '_') + "__" + x['set']
        fileName_crop = cardname + "_crop.jpg"
        print(fileName_full)
        time.sleep(.1)
        urllib.urlretrieve(cropUrl, fileName_crop)
```

Comment: It's possible that your `print` calls are being buffered.  Try doing `print('Whatever', flush=True)` to force the OS to output them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

A great, easy, and accepted library for HTTP requests is `requests`.

[Read the requests documentation.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: I have tried using requests already too, it behaves the same way.

Comment: It is not about client it is slowness of backend side.

Comment: @WilliamMosley what is the URL you are accessing?

Comment: @AaronZolla here is an example url it tries https://img.scryfall.com/cards/normal/en/dom/135.jpg?1524791340

Comment: @Alderven I can access the backend just fine though outside of my script

Comment: So what is download time for that specific url?

Comment: @Alderven last night it wouldn't get past the first one, but granted I only let it run your 4 or 5 minutes. I am about to head to work so I will leave it running until I get back and see if it finishes any.